# New Relic error rate alert doesn't work (AWS environment)

Tags: newrelic

I'm a beginner of New Relic. (only 2 days experience)

I registered New Relic through this page.
http://newrelic.com/aws

And I use EC2(Amazone Linux AMI), I installed New Relic packages according to this guideline.
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/servers/new-relic-servers-linux/installation-configuration/servers-installation-redhat-centos

And I installed New Relic PHP package. (I'm developing a website by PHP)

And now everything works fine except for **`'error rate'`** alert.

`'Server alert'` or `'Downtime alert'` works fine so that I can receive notification email.

**I set**

```
'caution error rate' to '1 % after 3 mins',
```

**And**

```
'Send alerts error rate' to '2 % after 3 mins'.
```

And I generate several errors on my site and I can see error rate over 50 % on New Relic's Event-Erros page for over 5 minutes.

Does anyone know how to setup and **`trigger 'error rate' notification`**?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused between Application monitors(PHP) and Server monitors(Linux)

The Server monitor does not collect an error rate. It isn't possible to alert on an error rate for your OS:
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/alert-policies/understanding-alert-policies/server-monitor-alerting#alert_scope

The PHP Application has an error rate for uncaught exceptions. The monitor will report these in the error rate. You can then create an application alert policy.

---

The important question is, does your php have an error rate when you generated errors? Are these being picked up for you?

If yes, double check your alert policy configuration, if you are getting server alerts you have a correct server policy. Look for the Application policy and ensure it uses the same alert channel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes I know Application monitoring and Server monitoring are different. So I use **Application alert policies** page and I can see PHP errors on **Error Rate** page (e.g. syntax error, class not found error) and its error rate is obviously over my error rate setting. And I can receive **Alert when any ping URL is unresponsive for ...** alert mail.

Comment: Hey ken, It sounds like you are looking in the right location and you should be receiving an alert. I work for NR support and can check your alert settings (and our email system for evidence that we did send an email) Can you post a link to your alert policy?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Taibhse again! Our application alert policy url is 'https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/882480/application_alert_policies?policy_id=327923'. I'd appreciate it if you could check my alert settings. Thanks a lot and I'm very sorry for my late reply.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry again I received alert email just now! I set Error Rate Alert like this: 
Caution : `1.0% after 3 mins`
Send Alerts : `1.5% after 4 mins`
And I generated many php errors on my web sites for over 5 minutes. Maybe We should set 'mins' of Send Alerts setting value a little bigger than Caution alert setting? I don't know background but it worked.

Comment: Hi, Your settings look correct and I can see that emails were sent to you without bouncing. Cautions will change application status from green to yellow to attract attention. While the critical setting will trigger an alert. As you saw, it needs to be constant to trigger an alert. So over 1.5% errors for four minutes to trigger an alert.  You also need a minimum of 10 requests per minute for alerts to trigger. [Here is a link to a doc on this](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/alert-policies/understanding-alert-policies/minimum-throughput-alerts)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply @Taibhse! **You also need a minimum of 10 requests per minute for alerts to trigger**, I understand.Maybe my previous alert test required more requests. I have to learn more. Now everything works fine! Thanks.